# Docker - denied: requested access to the resource is denied - when pushing image

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I create an image called `a`.
I login using `docker login` command and it returns `Login Succeeded`. Then I tag the image with:

```
docker tag a:1.4 myusername/a:1.4
```

I try pushing it:

```
docker push myusername/a:1.4
```

But I get this:

```
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you pushing to a private repository?  You would need to tag your image with the registry host and port rather than your username, eg:

```
docker login <REGISTRYHOST>:<REGISTRYPORT>
docker tag a:1.4 <REGISTRYHOST>:<REGISTRYPORT>/a:1.4
docker push <REGISTRYHOST>:<REGISTRYPORT>/a:1.4
```

Comment: No. I want to push it to docker hub. Isn't it the default behavior? I didn't change anything. How can I make sure that I'm actually pushing to docker hub?

Comment: Yes that is the default, try docker push username/a without the tag suffix since you have assigned this in the previous tag command